# Trying to add an SSH key to Key Management section of Admin

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration, key-management

Trying to add a key, and the client sent me the key information (one long ungodly string)... but, I'm not sure how to add it into the platform.  It looks like I need to 'browse' to add a file so I pasted the key value into a simple TXT file, added it to the platform, but I'm receiving an error when we try to save it.

What gives?  What are we missing here?

[image: key placement]

[image: error]

Comment: It is being caused by not including a Passphrase. I know that this is optional for SSH keys, but for some reason it is not optional in SFMC. I have only had success adding in the key if I have a corresponding Passphrase attached to it. I have had multiple cases in with SFMC support and explored many different options and nothing else has worked for me.

Comment: interesting... but if the key doesn't require it (because we're on the other side of the equation), can I put in a bogus key?

Comment: The key has to be in OpenSSH format, which is an option to export in PuttyGen with Conversions -> Export OpenSSH Key

Comment: The passphrase isn't required unless you used one when creating the key.

Comment: Oh that's good to know! Sweet gonna check that out tomorrow thanks @adamspriggs

Comment: Just wanted to verify that @AdamSpriggs is 100% correct! That is awesome, thanks for sharing!

Comment: I tried, but keep getting an error

`Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair'.`

Answer (score 1):

To properly create your SSH Key pairs I would suggest checking out the Knowledge Article posted in the Trailblazer Community:
[Error 'Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object' when saving SSH key](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351780&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1). This may help solving the issue.

As mentioned by @Adam Spriggs, PuTTY Gen provides you the possibility to export your Key in OpenSSH format. It is worth mentioning here when uploading a new Key, under Key Management, Marketing Cloud may not accept the file format generated by PuTTY Gen. It may depend on which version you are using. To avoid such errors, I would suggest exporting your file in **.txt** for both public and private keys.

Hope that helps!